# Characterizing fullness of a von Neumann algebra by the topology of its bimodules

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, bimodules

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor. Among other characterizations, it is said to be full iff the adjoint map:
$$
  \mathrm{Ad}: U(\mathcal{M})/\mathbb{T} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{M}),
$$
given by $\mathrm{Ad}([u])(x) = u x u^*$ is a homeomorphism onto the inner automorphisms $\mathrm{Inn}(\mathcal{M})$, where $U(\mathcal{M})$ represents the unitary group of $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{M})$ is the space of normal $\ast$-automorphisms and the corresponding topologies are given by pointwise norm convergence in the predual. I.e. $\alpha_n \to \alpha$ iff $\|(\alpha_n)_\ast(\varphi) - \alpha_\ast(\varphi) \|_{\mathcal{M}_\ast} \to 0$.

On the other hand, let us denote by $\mathrm{Bimod}(\mathcal{M})$ the space
$$
\mathrm{Bimod}(\mathcal{M}) = \Big\{ H :  {}_{\mathcal{M}}H_{\mathcal{M}}  \mbox{ is a Hilbert } \mathcal{M}\mbox{-}\mathcal{M}\mbox{-bimodule} \Big\}
$$
By $\mathcal{M}$-bimodule we mean a Hilbert spaces $H$ with two commuting normal actions of $\mathcal{M}$, one right one and one left one. The natural equivalence relation between bimodules is given by the existence of a unitary isometry that respects the actions. The Automorpism group of the von Neumann algebra embeds into the space of bimodules by taking $H(\alpha)$ as $L^2(\mathcal{M})$ with actions given by
$$
 x \cdot \xi \cdot y = \alpha(x) \xi  y.
$$
It is trivial to see that $H(\alpha) \cong H(\beta)$ iff $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal modulo the inner automorphism, see [AP, p 211].

> **Question:** Is it possible to characterize fullness by a topological property of $\mathrm{Bimod}(\mathcal{M})$. I think of something along
>   the lines of the equivalence classes of $\mathrm{Bimod}(\mathcal{M})$
>   being closed or perhaps by the quotient $\mathrm{Bimod}(\mathcal{M})
>  / \sim$ having some separability property.

There is a natural Fell's topology on $\mathrm{Bimod}(\mathcal{M})$ that behaves like the usual Fell topology of the space of representations of a group, see [AP, 13.3.2.]. But i am not sure whether that would be the adequate topology to use.

[AP] : http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIun-v13.pdf

---

This question was posted before in math.stackexchange.com without receiving an answer.

Comment: Is the argument given by Ozawa here (for separable II-1 factors) the kind of thing you're looking for? https://mathoverflow.net/a/323282/

Comment: Yes. Although that is not what I have in mind originally. I thought that, since $H(\alpha)$ is weakly eq. with $H(id) = L_2(\mathcal M)$ when $\alpha$ is approximately inner, imposing that the Fell-topology closures of two bimodules are equal iff the bimodules are isomorphic will be equivalent to fullness.  But that is too strong. Ozawa's answer gives the correct version of what I wanted.